# ios - making a remote call works on emulator but can not get it to work from live devices

Tags: ios, nsurl, nsurlrequest, nsoperationqueue

I have a bit of a confusing situation. I have a form after which I create a url and make an asynchronous server call. That data does not need to be secure.

Here is what I have:

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://my.url.com/script_name.php?subject=hardcoded_string&body=";

NSString *inputString = textArea.text;

NSString *url_to_send = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", urlString , inputString];         

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:url_to_send];
NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url ];

NSOperationQueue *queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
...
```

Is there something that I am doing incorrectly here in how I create the url?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that `url` is OK (non-nil) when `URLWithString` returns?

Comment: @Phillip Mills you mean the value that the server returns?

Comment: No, I mean your `url` object.  The docs for that method say, *"If the string was malformed, returns nil."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems ok... take a look at asihttprequest libs, on google... that's a powerful wrapper for http connections... you should now set up the queue and add the request to the queue. finally you have to start the queue.